# Why does admin.addPeer() work from certain nodes but not others?

Tags: ethereum, web3js, go-ethereum

I noticed that with a node on my AWS instance and geth node on my laptop, my AWS node can add my laptop as a peer, but my laptop cannot add my AWS instance.

Both nodes use a similar geth command line to the following:

```
geth --identity "node2" --rpc --rpcport "8000" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "./" --port "30303" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 1432 --nat "any" console --nodiscover
```

Would anyone know the cause of this behavior?